# Como convertir datos de ng-repeat en variable?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in students">
    <h2>{{item.student_name}}</h2>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in courses| filter:{studen_id: item.student_id}">
    <h2>{{item.course_title}}</h2>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar solo los cursos en el que esta suscrito el alumno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo añade el `ng-repeat` de `courses` dentro del `ng-repeat` de `students`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in students">
   <h2>{{item.student_name}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="item in courses| filter:{studen_id: item.student_id}">
      <p>{{item.course_title}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

También se puede filtrar los cursos desde `Javascript` , haciendo uso de [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) , retornando el método [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) aplicado a personas para verificar que los `id` sean iguales,  tanto el id Guardado en `Cursos` como `Estudiantes`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
var app = angular.module('Modulo', []);

app.controller('Controlador', function($scope) {
  $scope.personas = [
    {nombre : 'Jack', cursoid:1},
    {nombre : 'Jack1', cursoid:2},
    {nombre : 'Jack2', cursoid:3},
    ];
  $scope.cursos = [
    {nombre : 'Curso1', cursoid:1},
    {nombre : 'Curso2', cursoid:7},
    {nombre : 'Curso3', cursoid:3},
    ];

    $scope.test = $scope.cursos.filter(function (o) {
     return $scope.personas.some(function (i) {
         return i.cursoid == o.cursoid; 
    });
 });
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>
<div ng-app="Modulo">
   <div ng-controller="Controlador"> 
    <div ng-repeat="item in personas">
  <h2>{{item.nombre}}</h2>
      </div>
 <div ng-repeat="item1 in test">
  <h3>{{item1.nombre}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Dev Joel